# Как сделать GUI.Button нажатой по умолчанию в Unity

Tags: gui, unity3d

Как сделать чтобы кнопка была бы уже нажатой без действия пользователя?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, используя `EventSystem`:

```
EventSystemManager.currentSystem.SetSelectedGameObject(defaultButton, null);
```

где defaultButton - ваша кнопка, которая будет нажата без действий пользователя. И для примера внести данную строку в `Start()`